limit of infinite seqences
I am trying to prove this below proposition from real analysis royden pg 23 4th edition.
Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be real sequences, if $a_n <= b_n$ then $\limsup\{a_n\} <= \liminf\{b_n\}$
but I have found a counter example to disprove this, please correct me what I understood wrong or what is wrong with the counter example or is there a typo in question.
Let $\{b_n\} := \{4,2,4,2,4,2 ...\}$ and $\{a_n\} := \{3,1,3,1,3,1...\}$ then $\limsup\{a_n\} = 3 > 2 = \liminf\{b_n\}$

You are correct. The theorem correctly stated is $\forall n,m, ; a_n\leq b_m \implies \limsup(a_n)\leq \liminf(b_n)$

@Malady so my counter example is wrong, because when $n=1, m=2, a_n > b_m$ ? apologies for confirming this as I am not from maths major.

Your counter example to the theorem as stated was perfect! What I wrote is different (and correct), and yes that is exactly why your counterexample no longer holds.

@Malady thanks for further explanation, this was exactly was I was expecting.

proposition should state $\forall n,m, a_n\leq b_m$ for $\limsup(a_n) \leq \liminf(b_n)$ to hold, otherwise my counter example disproves the proof showing the proposition given to proof has a typo.

proof of $\forall n,m, a_n\leq b_m \implies \lim\sup\{a_n\} \leq \lim\inf\{b_n\}$
let $s_{a,n} := \sup\{a_k | k\geq n\}$ and $i_{b,n} := \inf\{b_k | k\geq n\}$
first proving $s_{a,n} \leq i_{b,n}$ by contradiction,
Assume $s_{a,n} \gt i_{b,n}$
then $\forall(k\geq n)[a_k \leq s_{a,n} > i_{b,n} \leq b_k]$ holds
$\exists k_1(k_1\geq n)[s_{a,n} \geq a_{k_1} \gt i_{b,n}]$ holds otherwise $s_{a,n} \leq i_{b,n}$
$\exists k_2(k_2\geq n)[b_{k_2} < a_{k_1}]$ holds otherwise $i_{b,n} \geq a_{k_1}$
$b_{k_2} \lt a_{k_1}$ is a contradiction implying $s_{a,n} \leq i_{b,n}$
Applying limit on both sides of $s_{a,n} \leq i_{b,n}$
$\lim_{n\to\infty} s_{a,n} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} i_{b,n}$
proof will also when $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded above or $\{b_n\}$ is not bounded below meaning when $s_{a,n}$ and $i_{b,n}$ are $\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively

@RedFive so I should remove this answer and add this as part of question ?

No ziabadar, your question and self-answer  are fine. @RedFive may have read them too quickly.

It was meant as a suggestion - there is nothing specifically wrong with the answer, I just felt at the time of being asked to review that it was better as an edit since it mentioned an error.

I have added proof of correct theorem.

+1 but that was un necessary. Your mention of the error was exactly answering the question.
